# how to replace a specific pattern from all files

Tags: bash, shell-script, replace

suppose I want to replace `abc` with `xyz` in all files in a directory. How do I write a script for this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`find . -type f | xargs sed -i 's/abc/xyz/g'`

Use `-maxdepth` option if you don't want the action to take place recursively in your current working directory.

Comment: `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | xargs sed -i 's/abc/xyz/g'` - this is non-recursive, ie., it will replace `abc` in the files that reside only in your current working directory.

Comment: you should use `find ... -exec sed '...' {} +`